# npm run dev is not loading the website at localhost:3000, NextJS project

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, next.js, npm-run

I am currently studying NextJS from a YouTube video, in between I encountered a bug.
When I run npm run dev for the first time the website gets loaded on port 3000 but if I terminate it regardless it's yes or no for 'terminate batch job' when I run npm run dev a second time the website just keeps on buffering, the console say it's ready but non of the events load.
Why is this happening? The only way I am able to run the app a second time is if I delete the ".next" folder and run npm run dev again.

Comment: `if I terminate it regardless it's yes or no for 'terminate batch job'` - what batch job is this?

Comment: Show your code, and logs from your terminal